# Header for MAXDOUBLE

Tags: c++

In what header is max value for double defined?

Comment: @David I've typed that and few other cominations but it didn't give me results expected by me. But I suppose to genius like you it's a different story.

Comment: Once you try "max value for double c++" and you find that most answers point to "numeric_limits" which you do not want to use (even if that is not clear in the question), you can just add that to the query: "max value for double c++ -numeric_limits". The first result is a C++.NET page, the second contains the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @David so I hope you admit now that your first comment doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`cfloat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/), which gives you `DBL_MAX`.

Answer (score 19):

```
#include <limits>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Maxvalue for double: " << std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're using C++ the standard way of achieving this is with:

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits< double >::max();
```

Answer (score 3):

On my system (VS 10) it's float.h. The define is DBL_MAX 1.7976931348623158e+308

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with VS, you can see this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx